# scope in rails 4 , how to add conditions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am using default scope in my model

```
def self.default_scope
    where ('locked_at IS NULL' )
end
```

so that no one can search for locked user , but i want if the logged-in user is admin , then he should able to find out locked user , i am not sure how it will work

in the database , in user table i have column name "admin" , which tell us who is admin .

i tried for session in model , but i think this is not a good idea , please suggest me something else

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you shouldn't place space between method and brackets with its arguments:

```
where('locked_at is NULL')
```

Second. If your admin is logged in, you should probably simply use `unscoped`:

```
User.unscoped
```

to avoid using your default scope.

Comment: can we unscoped only default scope ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`unscoped`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class) it return a scope for this class without taking into account the [**`default_scope`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class)

Something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      def self.default_scope
        where ('locked_at IS NULL')
      end
end

=> User.all            # Fires "SELECT * FROM users WHERE locked_at = NULL"
=> User.unscoped.all  if current_user.admin# Fires "SELECT * FROM users"
```

Don't forget to put the `if` condition after unscoped. Because as you mentioned that user table has `admin` column and I assume it has boolean type. If it's `true` then only it should unscoped.